# How to put a name in uppercase?

Tags: ruby

Here below is a picture of the challenge that i have to complete. I already tried two ways to solve this problem but i still can't fix it.

[image]

Here below is the snippet of how i tried to solve the problem. It might not make sense at all because i tried to solve the problem by applying what i can remember from learning Ruby a while ago. **Like explained in the picture above please do not change the code that is outside the "# Please write your code below this line..." and the "# ...and above this line." comment.**

```js
my_name = "Jordan"

# Please write your code below this line...

# The first way i tried to fix this problem
def my_name(name)
  upper = my_name.upcase
  my_name = upper.upcase! 

# Second way i tried to to fix this problem 

def my_name(name)
  upper = my_name.upcase
  upper.upcase!
end

# ...and above this line.

puts "My name is #{upper(my_name)}"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is generally not the place to just plop down your homework questions and ask us to do all the work. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Are you running into a specific error?

Comment: Yeah sorry i will change my question so that it shows what i have done to fix this problem. Just give me a few minutes.

Comment: I just edited my question. You can now see in the snippet of how i tried to fix this problem myself.

Comment: "i still can't fix it" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Here's a hint: take the code snippet provided to you with the assignment. Run it. It will raise an error. Read the error. Do the simplest possible thing that will fix this immediate error. Run the code again. It will raise another error. Repeat until done. For example, if the error message says that it couldn't find a variable named `foo`, the simplest possible thing to fix it is to create that variable: `foo = nil`.

Comment: Here's another hint: read the first sentence of the assignment. Note the name of the method you are supposed to write. Read the first line of your code. Note the name of the method you are writing.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't:

puts "My name is #{my_name.upcase}"

work? If you want to make it into a method, you could just return the .upcase of the parameter given. I don't use ruby, so I wouldn't know as much as others, though.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

https://apidock.com/ruby/String/upcase

Just call the method upcase of the class String

```
"jordan".upcase
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def upper(str, target)
  str.gsub(/\b#{target}\b/i) { |s| s.upcase }
end
```

```
target = "jordan"

upper("My name is Jordan", target)
  #=> "My name is JORDAN" 
upper("My name is Bob", target)
  #=> "My name is Bob" 
upper("My name is Jordanny", target)
  #=> "My name is Jordanny" 
upper("My name is Bojordan", target)
  #=> "My name is Bojordan

upper("My name is Bob", "bob")
  #=> "My name is BOB"
```

The word breaks (`\b`) prevent matches in the last two examples. See [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub). Note:

```
/\b#{target}\b/i
  #=> /\bjordan\b/i
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers provide sufficient solutions, but I wanted to share *why* this is happening to you. You were close but there's a little nuance to the way [upcase!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-upcase-21) works that isn't intuitive

You original code snippet has this:

```
upper = my_name.upcase
```

The `my_name.upcase` method takes your input, `Jordan`, and upcases it (just like you expect) and assigns it to the `upper` variable.

But, you also had this line:

```
my_name = upper.upcase!
```

Which is equivalent to `"JORDAN".upcase!` (because the first `upcase` call already upcased the text for you. Per the ruby docs I linked above, this method returns `nil` *if no changes were made*. Since you already upcased the word, no changes are made, so it returns nil

You can use one of the solutions in the other others, or simply delete the 2nd line where you call `upcase!`

This is all you really need to do:

```
def my_name(name)
  name.upcase
end
```